# In-place std::copy_if

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

It appears to me that `std::copy_if` would be very useful for filtering containers:

```
std::vector<int> vec { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
auto itEnd = std::copy_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(),
                          [](int i) { return i > 2; });
vec.resize(itEnd - vec.begin());
```

However, `std::copy_if` is specified that the input and output ranges may not overlap.

Is there an alternative?

Comment: Wouldn't `remove_if` solve your problem much more nicely?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`copy_if` is primarily for copying a range to another range/container I.e. by design, the nature of the algorithm is to copy the elements satisfying some condition to another (non-overlapping) range or to a new container.

`remove_if` is more appropriate for what you need; it is exactly for filtering out as you expect. However, it only removes the elements by overwriting; the remnants between the old and new ends would be unspecified elements after the function's completion and needs to be manually erased using `erase`, like so:

```
std::vector<int> vec { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
vec.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(vec),
                         std::end(vec),
                         [](int i) { return i <= 2; }),
          std::end(vec));
```

This is a C++ idiom that goes by the name [erase-remove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

---

Instead of `copy_if`, if `copy` was what you wanted, then you've an alternative for overlapping ranges, namely `copy_backward`; from [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

> If d_first is within [first, last), std::copy_backward must be used
>   instead of std::copy.

Comment: Your last paragraph is incorrect: There won't be a shift of all elements after each remove (which would result in O(n^2) performance). The performance will be linear, similar to that of `copy_if`.

Comment: @Yakk that comment was referring to an older version of the answer, I've deleted it now.

Comment: @legends2k: The standard does not mandate implementation, but it does mandate performance characteristics. So no, a conforming implementation may not take O(n^2).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Can you show a reference for that? Looking into `[alg.remove]`, I see "*Complexity:* Exactly `last - first` applications of the corresponding predicate." No mention of the number of copy/move operations.

Comment: @legends2k which of those do you think are O(n^2)?

Comment: @legends2k The possible implementations you linked are linear time, and do not act as you said.

Comment: @legends2k, those example implementations don't take O(n^2) though, and it would be very silly to write `remove_if` to be O(n^2) as there is no advantage to doing it that way

Comment: @Angew: You provided the reference yourself. The standard is tying the complexity to the number of applications of the predicate. So unless the cost of copying and moving is precisely zero, the implication is obviously that the number of copy/move operations is either directly proportional to that number, or less. It cannot be of a greater complexity than linear, otherwise that is how they would define the complexity.

Comment: @Angew Even if the standard doesn't mandate linear performance (I don't know if it does), every reasonable implementation will have linear performance, and I doubt you can find an implementation that acts as this answer describes.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Good point, I somehow failed to consider this reading of the text.

Comment: @interjay: I was hasty, I stand corrected. I worked it out on a pen and paper, and yes, it's linear for both the implementations. Fixed the answer, thanks!

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Thanks for giving me the clarity on how the complexity is linear was implied in the standard!

Comment: If the elements orders do not matters, then `std::partition` is a better algorithm in term of complexity compared to remove_if.